# My program takes much time to change an Excel file

Tags: c#, excel

I open excel file with c#, I make change and after save, but I have a problem, my program takes much time to do this. What I can do ?

How I can do for my program will be more quickly ?

Here I put my code:

I have a one file Form1.c:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using RutaExcel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Excel_Path
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static string pathOut = null;
        static string pathLogOut = null;
        static string pathOrigen = null;
        static string NameLog = null;
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern Boolean AllocConsole();
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern Boolean FreeConsole();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AllocConsole();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void folderBrowserDialog2_HelpRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void maskedTextBox2_MaskInputRejected(object sender, MaskInputRejectedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void maskedTextBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            folderBrowserDialog2.ShowDialog();
            maskedTextBox2.Text = folderBrowserDialog2.SelectedPath;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Agafem les rutes per copiar els fitxers d'excel
            pathOrigen = maskedTextBox2.Text;
            pathOut = @"C:\";
            string[] words = pathOrigen.Split('\\');
            int LengthWord = words.Length;
            NameLog = words[LengthWord - 1];
            pathLogOut = pathOut + NameLog + ".txt";

            // This text is added only once to the file.
            if (File.Exists(pathLogOut))
            {
                File.Delete(pathLogOut);
            }
            if (Directory.Exists(pathOut))
            {
                // Create a file to write to.
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(pathLogOut))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("Ficheros que se han pasado correctamente");
                    sw.WriteLine();
                }
                RutaExcel.Program.DirSearch(pathOrigen, pathOut, pathLogOut);
                RutaExcel.Program.FileSearch(pathOrigen, pathOut, pathLogOut);
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(pathLogOut))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine();
                    sw.WriteLine("Proceso de guardado finalizado");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("¡Hecho!");
                Console.ReadLine();
                FreeConsole();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And second file Main.c

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using VBA = Microsoft.Vbe.Interop;

namespace RutaExcel
{
    public class Program
    {
        static int IndexFile = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }

        public static void read_file(string file, string dir, string pathOut, string pathLogOut)
        {
            //Antes de nada, miramos el formato que tiene el fichero que nos entra. Si el fichero en cuestion no tiene ninguna extension de excel,
            //no hacemos nada.
            string[] words = file.Split('.');
            int LengthWord = words.Length;
            string fileFormat = words[LengthWord - 1];
            //Verificamos el formato que tiene el fichero de entrada. Si es excel seguimos con el proceso.
            if (fileFormat == "XLS" || fileFormat == "xls" || fileFormat == "XLSX" || fileFormat == "xlsx" || fileFormat == "XLSM" || fileFormat == "xlsm" ||
               fileFormat == "XLSB" || fileFormat == "xlsb" || fileFormat == "XLT" || fileFormat == "xlt" || fileFormat == "XLA" || fileFormat == "xla")
            {
                try
                {
                    if (!File.Exists(file))
                        return;

                    //Path para el fichero destino
                    string fileDestiny = file.Replace(@"IN\", "");
                    Console.WriteLine(fileDestiny);
                    //Si el fichero ya exisita lo borramos para no crear ficheros corruptos
                    if (File.Exists(fileDestiny))
                    {
                        File.SetAttributes(fileDestiny, FileAttributes.Normal);
                        File.Delete(fileDestiny);
                    }

                    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(fileDestiny);
                    try
                    {
                        // Determine whether the directory exists.
                        if (di.Exists)
                        {
                            // Indicate that the directory already exists.
                            Console.WriteLine("That path exists already.");
                            return;
                        }
                        // Try to create the directory.
                        di.Create();
                        Console.WriteLine("The directory was created successfully.");

                        // Delete the directory. Sirve para eliminar el acceso a ese directorio.
                        di.Delete();
                        Console.WriteLine("The directory was deleted successfully.");
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
                    }

                    //Copio el fichero original en otro directorio. Si el fichero original tiene permisos de solo lectura, la copia que hago tambien los tendra.
                    //Así pues, lo que haremos sera quitarle dichos permisos a la copia para poder modificar el contenido y despues, al acabar dicho proceso,
                    //volveremos a poner los permisos corresponientes a la copia modificada.
                    System.IO.File.Copy(file, fileDestiny, true);
                    FileAttributes attributes = File.GetAttributes(fileDestiny);
                    File.SetAttributes(fileDestiny, FileAttributes.Normal);

                    Excel.Application xlApp;
                    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = null;
                    Excel.Range range = null;

                    var misValue = Type.Missing;//System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

                    // abrir el documento
                    xlApp = new Excel.Application();
                    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
                    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileDestiny, misValue, misValue,
                        misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue,
                        misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);

                    //Si el excel contiene macros creadas a partir de Visual Basic, exportamos las macros al nuevo fichero destino.
                    //Al exportar dichas macros, se crean unos ficheros con extension .bas dentro del directorio donde nos situamos.
                    //Una vez tenemos los ficheros exportados, estos los sobreescribimos con los cambios pertinentes.
                    //Una vez hecho todo esto, borramos los archivos .bas que se han ido creando en la carpeta origen.
                    VBA.VBProject project = xlWorkBook.VBProject;
                    VBA.VBComponents VBComponents = project.VBComponents;
                    string filePath = null;
                    foreach (VBA.VBComponent Component in VBComponents)
                    {
                        if (Component.Type == VBA.vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule)
                        {
                            Component.Export(pathOut + Component.Name + ".bas");
                            filePath = pathOut + Component.Name + ".bas";

                            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.Default);
                            string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            reader.Close();

                            content = Regex.Replace(content, @"T:\\", @"T:\Gestion\");

                            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, false, Encoding.Default);
                            writer.Write(content);
                            writer.Close();

                            Component.CodeModule.DeleteLines(1, Component.CodeModule.CountOfLines);
                            Component.CodeModule.AddFromFile(filePath);
                            File.Delete(filePath);
                        }
                    }

                    foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in xlWorkBook.Sheets)
                    {
                        // seleccion rango activo
                        range = sheet.UsedRange;
                        // leer las celdas
                        int rows = range.Rows.Count;
                        int cols = range.Columns.Count;
                        for (int row = 1; row <= rows; row++)
                        {
                            for (int col = 1; col <= cols; col++)
                            {
                                if (!(range.Cells[row, col].Value == null))
                                {
                                    string valorBar = range.Cells[row, col].Formula.Replace(@"C:\", @"C:\Gestion\");
                                    range.Cells[row, col].Formula = valorBar;
                                    Console.WriteLine(valorBar);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        // liberar
                        releaseObject(sheet);
                    }

                    // Guardar y cerrar
                    Excel.XlFileFormat FileFormat = xlWorkBook.FileFormat;
                    xlWorkBook.SaveAs(fileDestiny, FileFormat);
                    xlWorkBook.Close();

                    //Volvemos a poner los permisos predeterminados que tenia el fichero copiado de excel.
                    File.SetAttributes(fileDestiny, attributes);

                    // liberar
                    releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
                    releaseObject(xlApp);
                    //Escribir en un archivo, los ficheros que se han ido pasando.
                    IndexFile = IndexFile + 1;
                    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(pathLogOut))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(IndexFile + "." + file + " --> Hecho");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("El fichero {0} no se ha guardado correctamente! {1}", file, e.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        public static void releaseObject(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
                obj = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to release the object(object:{0})", obj.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                obj = null;
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }

        public static void DirSearch(string sDir, string pathOut, string pathLogOut)
        {
            try
            {
                string[] DirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(sDir);
                foreach (string d in DirectoryEntries)
                {
                    foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d))
                    {
                        read_file(f, d, pathOut, pathLogOut);
                    }
                    DirSearch(d, pathOut, pathLogOut);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception excpt)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
            }
        }

        public static void FileSearch(string d, string pathOut, string pathLogOut)
        {
            try
            {
                string[] FilesEntries = Directory.GetFiles(d);
                foreach (string f in FilesEntries)
                {
                    read_file(f, d, pathOut, pathLogOut);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception excpt)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: First thing you can do is share your code!

Comment: Include your code so that other developers can see where it may be going wrong. Simply pasting this question without enough details will only get it voted down.

Comment: There is no magic trick that works for every performance issue. Share your code

Comment: Okey, I share my code!

Comment: What you can do is optimise and improve your code. Only you can do that since you declined to show any code. Good luck.

Comment: Hope you weren't reading one cell-> save and so on

Comment: Okey, now I can't put my code because I don't have sufficient reputation

Comment: I edit my answer and i put my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this will work since I do not have your excel file, but

One thing you can do is Create a larger range instead of one cell at a time.

for this code - it looks like you are walked every row and column to replace `C:\` with `C:\Gestion`.

```
 range = sheet.UsedRange;
                    // leer las celdas
                    int rows = range.Rows.Count;
                    int cols = range.Columns.Count;
                    for (int row = 1; row <= rows; row++)
                    {
                        for (int col = 1; col <= cols; col++)
                        {
                            if (!(range.Cells[row, col].Value == null))
                            {
                                string valorBar = range.Cells[row, col].Formula.Replace(@"C:\", @"C:\Gestion\");
                                range.Cells[row, col].Formula = valorBar;
                                Console.WriteLine(valorBar);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

try the following

```
 range = sheet.UsedRange;
 // leer las celdas
 int rows = range.Rows.Count;
 int cols = range.Columns.Count;

 var startCell = (Range)WorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
 var endCell = (Range)WorkSheet.Cells[rows, cols];
 var range = WorkSheet.Range[startCell, endCell];

 range.Formula.Replace(@"C:\", @"C:\Gestion\");
 range.Formula = valorBar;
```

Comment: Well, the range is declare on the top, but you declare again here:

Comment: Well, the variable range is declare on top of this program, but you declare again here var range = WorkSheet.Range[startCell, endCell];

And so, the variable valorBar, in your code, is nothing

Comment: I try this code, but it doesn't work well. Can you help me please ? Thanks!

Comment: My code stop in this code "range.Formula.Replace(@"C:\", @"C:\Gestion\");"

Comment: This it's work:  range = sheet.UsedRange;
                        // leer las celdas
                        int rows = range.Rows.Count;
                        int cols = range.Columns.Count;

                        Excel.Range startCell = sheet.Cells[1, 1];
                        Excel.Range endCell = sheet.Cells[rows, cols];
                        sheet.Range[startCell, endCell].Formula = "Hola";

Comment: But I want to replace Formula.Replace(@"C:\", @"C:\Gestion\"); But I can't